# Passing variables from one file to another (PHP)

Tags: php, forms, post, get, webclient

so I am creating this report page where the users get to select the type of report and the dates. Once they click the submit button, 2 new buttons will display, one to download the report in excel and another to download in PDF. Based on the type of report selected I have specific files that will process the report. I have tested the specific files and they do generate the report correctly, when I use a hard coded date. But I want to be able to use the dates selected by the user. Please take a look at my code and let me know what I am missing. Thank you!!

saereport.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <TITLE>SAE Report</TITLE>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$().ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
});
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<h1>SAE Report</h1>
</center>
 <form action = "" method = "post">
 <label>Report Type</label>
    <select id="report" name="report">
        <option value="none"></option>
        <option value="new">New SAEs Report</option>
        <option value="cumulative">Cumulative SAE Report</option>
    </select>
 <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start">
 <label>End Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<?php
$type='';
$start='';
$end='';

if (isset($_post['submit'])){

    $type=$_post['report'];
    $start=$_post['start'];
    $end=$_post['end'];

    if ($type=="cumulative"){
        echo "<form action='cumulativeRptExcel2.php?='.$end. method='get' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<form action='$cumulativePDF' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    elseif($type=='new' and $startdt!='' and $enddt!=''){
        echo "<form action='$newXLS' method='get' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<form action='$newPDF' method='get' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    elseif($type="new" and ($start=='' or $end=='')){
        echo "You need to select START and END date for the report";
    }   
}
?>
```

The beginning of my cumulativeRptExcel2.php:

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');
$endDT='';
if (isset($_get['enddt'])){ 
   $endDT=$_get['enddt'];
}
$query="SELECT * from sae_cumulative_report2($endDT)";
$result = pg_query($db, $query);
...
?>
```

Comment: You need to set the the form's action with cumulativeRptExcel2.php

Comment: but depending on the report selection the processing file is different. So if I put cumulativeRptExcel2.php in the form action, the variables will always be passed to the same file, no? This way a 'new' type report wouldn't be able to generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to generate the buttons so the user could select which download file they wanted (xls or pdf). For now, I ended up just automatically downloading the Excel file. Here it is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <TITLE>SAE Report</TITLE>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $().ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
 });
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<center>
<h1>SAE Report</h1>
</center>
 <form action = "processReport.php" method = "GET">
 <label>Report Type</label>
    <select id="report" name="report">
        <option value="none"></option>
        <option value="new">New SAEs Report</option>
        <option value="cumulative">Cumulative SAEs Report</option>
    </select>
 <label>Start Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start">
 <label>End Date</label><input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</BODY>
```

processReport.php:

```
$type='';
$startdt='';
$enddt='';
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

    $type=$_GET['report'];
    $startdt=$_GET['start'];
    $enddt=$_GET['end'];

    if ($type=="cumulative" and $enddt!=''){
        $query="SELECT * from sae_cum_decoded('$enddt')";
        $filename='SAE_CumulativeReport_';
        $insideTitle="Cumulative SAEs Report";
        processFile($db,$filename, $insideTitle,$query);
    }
    elseif($type=='new' and $startdt!='' and $enddt!=''){
        $query="SELECT * from sae_new_decoded('$startdt','$enddt')";
        $filename='SAE_NewReport_';
        $insideTitle="New SAEs Report";
        processFile($db,$filename, $insideTitle,$query);
    }
    else
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("In order to generate a report, a REPORT TYPE needs to be selected.\nFor Cumulative SAEs Report, END DATE is required.\nFor New SAEs Report, START DATE and END DATE are required.")
        window.location.href="saereport5.php"';
        echo '</script>';


}

function processFile($db,$filename, $insideTitle, $query){
...}
```

Would be nice to figure out how to do this using the buttons, because in the future the user will need to have both options.

Comment: I have updated the code to use the buttons as wanted. There was a syntax problem in the form pointing to the `cumulativeRptExcel2.php` file and also the GET method was being used with the variables being passed through query string

Comment: Valeu! Gosteu da técnica de usar name="start"

Answer (score 0):

A few comments before the code:

1. The variable name is case-sensitive. Use `$_POST` instead of `$_post`, as mentioned by @toh19;
   Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php
2. Do not trust user input directly. In this case to be in a safer side you could validate the user input against regular expressions.
   Reference: http://www.phptherightway.com/#data_filtering

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
        <TITLE>
            SAE Report
        </TITLE>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $().ready(function() {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}
                                           );
            }
                     );
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <center>
            <h1>
                SAE Report
            </h1>
        </center>
        <form action = "" method = "post">
            <label>Report Type</label>
            <select id="report" name="report">
                <option value="none"></option>
                <option value="new">New SAEs Report</option>
                <option value="cumulative">Cumulative SAE Report</option>
            </select>
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="end">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
<?php
$type='';
$start='';
$end='';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $type=$_POST['report'];
    $start=$_POST['start'];
    $end=$_POST['end'];
    if ( $type == 'cumulative') {
        echo "<form action='cumulativeRptExcel2.php?&enddt=$end' method='POST' name='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<form action='$cumulativePDF' method='post' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    elseif ($type == 'new') {
        if (empty($start) || empty($end)) {
            die("You need to select START and END date for the report");
        }
        echo "<form action='$newXLS' method='get' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download Excel'/>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<form action='$newPDF' method='get' name ='xls'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitXLS' value='Download PDF'/>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
}
```

**Update**

- There was a syntax issue in the previous code (in the form action of the cumulative type);
- If you want to pass the variable through query string (`cumulativeRptExcel2.php?&enddt=...`) you have to change the form `METHOD` to `POST`, otherwise (GET method) you need to create a hidden field for the enddt value;

Comment: Still the file was not able to identify the parameters being passed.